# Angular material overlay above of an element

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to append an overlay **below** the targeted element and it works, but it seems that i cannot append it on **top** of the targeted element.

```
<button (mouseenter)="openFusilliPanel()" (mouseleave)="closeFusilliPanel()">
   Hover to append
</button>

<!-- I would like to append it above this DIV element -->
<div cdkOverlayOrigin #tortelliniOrigin="cdkOverlayOrigin" #appendDiv style="background:pink;width:400px;height:100px;color:black;margin-top:100px;">Should append overlay on top of this element</div>

<!-- Template to load into an overlay. -->
<ng-template cdk-portal>
    <p style="background-color: mediumpurple;width:100px;" class="demo-fusilli"> Fusilli </p>
</ng-template>
```

Source

```
const positionStrategy = this.overlay.position().connectedTo(
    this.tortelliniOrigin.elementRef,
    { originX: 'start', originY: 'bottom' },
    { overlayX: 'start', overlayY: 'top' })
    .withFallbackPosition(
    { originX: 'start', originY: 'top' },
    { overlayX: 'start', overlayY: 'bottom' })
    .withFallbackPosition(
    { originX: 'end', originY: 'top' },
    { overlayX: 'start', overlayY: 'top' })
    .withFallbackPosition(
    { originX: 'start', originY: 'top' },
    { overlayX: 'end', overlayY: 'top' })
    .withFallbackPosition(
    { originX: 'end', originY: 'center' },
    { overlayX: 'start', overlayY: 'center' })
    .withFallbackPosition(
    { originX: 'start', originY: 'center' },
    { overlayX: 'end', overlayY: 'center' })
    ;
this.fusilliOverlayRef = this.overlay.create({ positionStrategy });
this.fusilliOverlayRef.attach(this.templatePortals.first);
```

How can i make the overlay(purple box) append on top of the pink box?
[image]

Demo link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/overlay-demo-2nssno

I was thinking that I am using `connectedTo()` which creates the overlay relative to the attached element, how can we set it to show `relative` above the attached element instead of bottom?

Does anyone know how to append overlay(purple) above (red box) of the targeted element(pink)?

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz of your issue please ?

Comment: Added demo link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found this to work.

```
        { originX: 'start', originY: 'top' },
        { overlayX: 'start', overlayY: 'bottom' })
```